# Apache Felix won't start

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I'm trying to start Apache Felix (`java -jar felix.jar`) from the Windows 7 cmd, but I get nothing. The cursor simply jumps to the next line which then remains blank and blinking forever. I don't get the Apache Felix success message, ie:

```
Welcome to Felix
================  

-> ps
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I start from the directory of the felix distribution it works for me.
I got a similar behaviour like you when I started directly from the bin directory as then the launcher did not find the config.properties.

It might also be about the java version. I used Java 8.

Comment: I missed the crucial bit of information in the documentation: "Start the framework from the installation directory by typing:
java -jar bin/felix.jar"